# Syntax highlight within a QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, pyqt, syntax-highlighting, pyside

I'm trying to find a way to syntax highlight some special words in a QTreeWidgetItem. for example, if the item's text contains both letters and numbers, I'll highlight the numbers only.

I am able to highlight the QTreeWidgetItem as a whole. But just can't do it within an item. Anyone has any idea?